# Are floors 76-100 still untouched?

Tags: sword-art-online

At the end of the Aincrad arc, Kirito faced Skull Reaper (boss of the floor) and found out that the Guild Master of the Knights of the Blood was the GM himself. After beating him, Aincrad was destroyed and floors 76-100 were still untouched.

At the end of the Fairy Dance arc, Kirito restores Aincrad so the people can explore it again.

[image: Aincrad restored (SAO S1 episode 25)]

I waiting for the story about floors 76-100, as well as the Ruby Palace (100th floor), but there has been nothing so far. Now that Kirito has begun exploring GGO (Gun Gale Online), are floors 76-100 still untouched?

Comment: Since they bought Aincrad into ALO, I'm sure the faeries are working to climb as well, but at a much more relaxed pace.

Comment: @Krazer You mean after the arc? Because at the begin till the end of the arc it was all about Yggdrasil no Aincrad. After the arc ended (anime related) with The Seed they rebuilt it so there is a possibility AFAIK that other players were exploring it even Kirito himself however I doubt it will be shown as an anime anytime soon. And I have not read the manga so I am basing myself on what have been seen on the anime.

Comment: Yeah pretty much, they basically ended up there.

Comment: at the end of sao 2 kirito said he was gonna climb aincrad and asked his sister if she wanted to go with him so im guessing in sao 3 they wil go back and clear the game for real

Comment: @user13787 The next arc involves Gun Gale Online. Do you have any sources to back this up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Still untouched in canon.  In the non-canon games Infinity Moment/Hollow Fragment, Kirito and the others had to continue through the upper floors and the Ruby Palace.

It was established within canon that the floors of New Aincrad are being released 10 floors at a time.  The Mother's Rosario story arc begins with the update that opened floors 21-30 to begin clearing, notable because Kirito and Asuna wanted to reclaim their cabin on floor 22.  Since nothing has been said beyond Mother's Rosario, it is safe to say the upper floors still have not been released.

Comment: To add my own knowledge. In the light novel, post gun-gale there is another arc that is currently underway. So it may come up in the next book somehow. Though it's only speculation at this point.

Answer (score 1):

There is no formal reference to this in manga/anime as far as I'm aware of, but chances are that it probably got cleared or in process of. Aincrad was revived and others are playing in it including Kirito (he commented how he would like to restart from level 1 and beat it properly this time). Unless he got bored, I'm sure he would only move on from the game after someone beats it properly.

The other probability is SAO II happens while he's still in pursuit of that goal.

Answer (score 1):

I was only implied in the light novel and anime, that Kirito would like to clear Aincrad. It was not told in detail about it as after ALO (Alfheim Online), the story moved to GGO (Gun Gale Online). Too bad the online reference in Baka-Tsuki is no longer available.

Source: I read the book from volume 1 to 6, that is from SAO (vol 1-2) to GGO (vol 5-6).

Answer (score 0):

In the last scene of *Sword Art Online Movie: Ordinal Scale* ...

> Kirito and his team are fighting the last boss on Floor 100, or the so-called Ruby Palace.

Comment: Can you add some more detail?

Comment: Based on traditional arc, the final boss on ruby palace are Heatcliff... also, if I remember correctly, on light novels the latest floors are untouched yet. Maybe, this scene can be a "spoiler" not based on the novels.